# Error in bulk updating of multiple columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.6. I am trying to update multiple users with corresponding values. Below is my code:

```
$cash_nov_updates[] = [
    'cash_to_be_paid_order_matched'    => $cash_to_be_paid_order_matched_user,
    'nov_to_be_given_order_matched'    => $nov_to_be_given_order_matched_user,
    'nov_to_be_obtained_order_matched' => $nov_to_be_obtained_order_matched_user,
];

CashNovOwnership::whereIn( 'user_id', $list_order_user_ids )
    ->update( $cash_nov_updates );
```

Upon running it is generating query like:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update 'cash_nov_ownership' set '0' = 0, '1' = 168.09, '2' = 377.05, '3' = 561.43, '4' = 561.43, '5' = 561.43, '6' = 561.43, '7' = 561.43, '8' = 561.43, '9' = 651.94, '10' = 717.24, '11' = 717.24, '12' = 924.12, '13' = 1067.78, '14' = 1331.18, '15' = 1331.18, '16' =

Comment: Where is $cash_sil_updates declared?

Comment: @Nagesh within a loop and I fixed the typo

Answer (score 1):

Laravel `update()` requires single dimansional array, please modify

```
$cash_nov_updates = [
                    'cash_to_be_paid_order_matched'    => $cash_to_be_paid_order_matched_user,
                    'nov_to_be_given_order_matched'    => $nov_to_be_given_order_matched_user,
                    'nov_to_be_obtained_order_matched' => $nov_to_be_obtained_order_matched_user,
                ];
```

Comment: So no way to update multiple rows with unique records in a single query?

Comment: @Volatil3 This will update multiple rows if the where condition matches with multiple records.

Comment: I have different values per row and what you suggest will set multiple records with same values which is not I am looking for.

Comment: How you decide, for which ID you update which array element? You need a separate query to update for a single ID.

Comment: This is what I thought about but I assumed `update()` will take care of it which you said it would not. Do I have to run Raw subqueries then?

Comment: yes, but it depends on how you construct an SQL query. Do you have a Raw SQL query for updating multiple values for multiple IDs? In my point of view, you need to loop through each ID in $list_order_user_ids and then update a different set of values for that ID.

Comment: https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/11/how-to-update-multiple-rows-at-once-in-mysql.html - Option #2, Most probably.